# grabbing the api dictionary json with python

Tags: python

I was following this tutorial on api grabbing with python:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pxofwuWTs7c

The url gives:

```
{"date":"1468500743","ticker":{"buy":"27.96","high":"28.09","last":"27.97","low":"27.69","sell":"27.97","vol":"41224179.11399996"}}
```

I tried to follow the video and grab the 'last' data.

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'https://www.okcoin.cn/api/v1/ticker.do?symbol=ltc_cny'
json_obj=urllib2.urlopen(url)
data= json.load(json_obj)
for item in data['ticker']:print item['last']
```

After typing the last line python returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: if you are just doing this in the python command line, press enter again.

Comment: the link to the tutorial is missing...

Comment: ``ticket`` key is not an Array so you can't iterate over it.

Comment: For me, this code times out on the `json_obj=urllib2.urlopen(url)` line, not sure why

Comment: @flazzarini, it's a dict so, yes it can be iterated. However, `print item['item']` will cause problems since it will iterate over the keys. OP, you probably want `if item == 'last': print data['ticker']['last']` or even better, the answer that flazzarini posted (taking out the for loop)

Comment: @RNar Yap that's correct, your solution would work as well!

Answer (score 4):

I think you just misread the payload returned by the server. In this case the `ticker` key is not of type `list` in the dictionary converted by the `json` module.

So You should do the following

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'https://www.okcoin.cn/api/v1/ticker.do?symbol=ltc_cny'
json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(json_obj)
print data['ticker']['last']
```